# Update 500 randomized rows in MySQL DB

Tags: mysql

How can I update 500 randomized rows in a MySQL database? I tried the following but it didn't work:

```
UPDATE `usr_usuarios` SET `feedback_solicitado` = 1 ODER BY RAND() LIMIT 500
```

Comment: What didn't work exactly? I think it is the correct way to do that.

Comment: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'ODER BY RAND() LIMIT 500' at line 1

Answer (score 1):

In order to get rows affected as 500 you can add extra `WHERE` condition as:

```
UPDATE usr_usuarios 
SET feedback_solicitado = 1 
WHERE feedback_solicitado <> 1 
ORDER BY RAND() 
LIMIT 500;
```

EDIT: as @Jocelyn said: you have done typo mistake `ODER` instead of `ORDER`

Answer (score 1):

To fix the syntax error you are getting, just replace `ODER` with `ORDER` in your query.

Answer (score 0):

Try this UUID() function

```
"UPDATE usr_usuarios SET feedback_solicitado = 1 ORDER BY UUID() LIMIT 500"
```

Comment: What is the benefit of UUID() over RAND() for random sorting?

Answer (score 0):

Since ,you are using ODER instead of ORDER, the query should be like this:

```
 UPDATE usr_usuarios 
       SET feedback_solicitado = 1
    ORDER
        BY RAND() LIMIT 500
```